# How do I specify options for filter.default?

Tags: php

I want to add a universal filters on form inputs that blocks all characters that are invalid in XML.

i.e. anything that doesn't fit: /[\x{0009}\x{000a}\x{000d}\x{0020}-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]+/u

The [filter.default configuration variable](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.configuration.php) seems like a good option, but it appears that I can only specify the name of a filter and some flags. There doesn't seem to be an existing filter/flag combination that accomplishes my goals. I'd like to use the [callback filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php) and simply run [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), but that would require a way for specifying the callback method. Is there any way to specify the value for the options parameter of the default filter?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php it appears that filter.default cannot be set at runtime (only in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini). This tells me that a callback wouldn't work as filter.default since the callback function doesn't exist by the time the variable is set.